# How to open a file from the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way of opening a file from the terminal in Visual Studio Code that opens in the *same* vscode instance that runs the terminal? Similar to [c9](https://superuser.com/questions/793988/open-file-from-cloud9s-terminal-bash-in-its-ide) tool in Cloud9.

I'm aware of the [code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) tool, but when you run `code something.php` from the integrated terminal it opens a **new** vscode instance, which is not what I want...

Comment: More challenging: I am using SSH in the integrated terminal and I would like to open a remote file...

Comment: With SSH I use `readlink -f something.php` to print the full path of the file, and then a `Ctrl+click` on the path open it in a new tab.

Comment: Now in 2022 the accepted answer works (at least for me) for remote SSH in integrated terminal. The `readlink` + `Ctrl+click` trick works as well.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You can use -r or --reuse-window command line option.

```
code -r something.php
```

Comment: Great, that works! Too bad it's slow as #@*, 3 seconds to open a file.

Comment: VERY convenient on stuff like **mkcd subfolder; touch SomeClass.js; code -r So`<pressing tab...+enter>`**

Comment: @JanJongboom can't confirm any slowness (Ubuntu MATE, vscodfe 1.18). Might be something on your machine...

Comment: Opens a new window for me on Windows 10 :/

Comment: @JanJongboom, 3 seconds is hardly slow for any human mind looking for a tab on the screen. A mouse hover and click takes about the same time.

Comment: The -r or --reuse-window option does not work for me, neither on Win7 nor on Win10.

Comment: @JanJongboom, I can confirm the slowness on Windows10, did you ever find a better solution?

Comment: -r did not for me too. edit: I was using wsl terminal, so watch out for that.

Comment: @AliMertCakar Did you get it to open in the SAME window via. Ubuntu WSL? I've this problem :(

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 yep, it works for me now. But I've upgraded to windows 11. It did not work for me with w10 before, now it works. I don't know is this 100% related but i didn't change anything else.

Comment: Ty for getting back, @AliMertCakar! This eventually worked with me... but only when I initially had a file open in a new window. I closed the old window and every time after I ran `code -r filename.extension` did it run in the same window.

Comment: Does not work for me. `-bash: code: command not found`

Comment: Perfectly works for me to open file on remote machine (Ubuntu hyper-v virtual machine) via SSH connection in VSCode on Windows 10 host.

Comment: Is there any way to integrate the command `code -r` so that the integrated PowerShell terminal always opens files in a new window without resorting to type `code -r`?

Answer (score 30):

just

```
code file_name
```

I tried it on Win10 and on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: Also works for me on Mac. It seems they simplified it since the times of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396173/711006) (2016).

Answer (score 23):

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (this opens "Command Palette")
3. Type `shell command`
4. Select “Install code command in path”
5. Navigate to any project from the terminal, and type `code .`

If it didn't work, select “Uninstall code command from path” first, then reinstall it again.

Comment: this was the most helpful answer for me

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer on Mac.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know what operating system you're using, but on MacOS you can just say `open filename.ext` in the integrated terminal, and it will open a new tab in the same VSCode instance, ready for you to edit.

Comment: Not for me on macOS 10.11... Have associated files with vscode, run `open something.php` and it opens a *new* vscode instance...

Comment: Interesting. I have macOS 10.12 Sierra and Visual Studio Code 1.8.1. The only custom settings I have in VSCode have nothing to do with the terminal.

Comment: Oh, and I use `zsh` as shell and `iTerm2 Build 3.0.13` if that's relevant.

Comment: This is actually faster than using the `code -r` command mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: For me too, on ubuntu 16.04, the -r option is not necessary. It opens in the current vscode window by default.

Comment: `open` uses your default application for the filetype, it may be vscode, it may be something else. `open -r filename` is the correct answer.

Comment: On Mac. I get that "-r" isn't an option. Reading through the help, it doesn't look like there is any option for "open" that will pull it up in current VS instance. macOS 11.4, VS Code 1.58.2

Comment: While @Francois solution works pretty well, it requires installing full code on external machine and that's not small 700+MB package...

Answer (score 9):

If you are having `command not found: code` in macOS, use a full path to it.

```bash
/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code -r [filename]
```

Answer (score 5):

I use `code -r .` to open the current directory in the main window.

Answer (score 5):

Many things can be found in `open --help`

A work around that worked for me on MacOS is:
`open -a 'Visual Studio Code.app' something.php`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `code` command from the CLI to open a file, but if you want it to open in the existing window, either use `code -r <file>` as mentioned in other answers (which *does* work for me on Ubuntu Linux), or, if `-r` does not work (under WSL?), make sure `window.openFilesInNewWindow` is either `off` or `default` in `settings.json` or the in VS Code settings UI, then use `code <file>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that it's helpful to know in which environment you're trying to run the command. If you're using Windows, the default shell for VSCode's integrated terminal is PowerShell, therefore, you can use the following commands interchangeably to open your files within your workspace as others suggested `code -r file_name.rb` or `code file_name.rb`.

Now, if you're using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), you will first need to install the WSL extension in VSCode. Once installed, you can connect to WSL either through "Open a Remote Window" or the "Remote Explorer." This will allow you to switch to your Linux distro within WSL and run the same commands mentioned above to open files within your workspace. Hope this adds some clarity for those of you hacking on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

in the version 1.31.0 that I have installed, on Windows 7, the only way I found to do this is to e.g. change the file associations in system so that .cproj and .cs files are opened by Visual Studio Code by default, and type "filename.cs" in Terminal to open file by that name in the same window... -r option is not working for the first call (opens a new window), but with each subsequent call that same window is correctly reused. ok can't get to open whole directories this way - it's a bit shoddy anyway. probably it would be more convenient to use an outside shell and work with "-r" option

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.64 (Jan. 2022) comes with a new command:

> ### [Keyboard Navigable Links](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#keyboard-navigable-links)
>
> Previously, link navigation in the terminal required the use of a mouse.
>
> Now, links can be opened using only the keyboard via the following commands:
>
> - **`Terminal: Open Detected Link...`** to view all links (web, file, word)
> - **`Terminal: Open Last Web Link...`** ex: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode
> - **`Terminal: Open Last File Link...`** ex: `/Users/user/repo/file.txt`

Check if the last command `Terminal: Open Last File Link...` would help in your case.

See also "[Terminal shell integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70918827/6309)"

[image: cwd -- open link]

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue, but I recently updated vscode (on a mac) and it seems like cmd+click'ing a hovered file link in the terminal now brings up the Go To File (cmd+p) window instead of just opening the file. If I ls'd a directory in the integrated terminal and wanted to open a file I was hovering over in a buffer, do you happen to know what the right command is now? Cmd+click used to work, and it was a lot more convenient that way.

Comment: @totalhack I have the same 1.66, but on Windows, and Ctrl+clicking the link does open the browser. For a file in folder of the integrated terminal, Ctrl+click does open the file in VSCode. Check the Terminal: Explorer Kind setting.

Comment: I think that might be something different. That is set to "integrated" but the description doesn't seem to be talking about the same thing. Based on [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_links) link it sounds like my problem is "if a file or URL cannot be detected, they are still surfaced as low confidence 'workspace search' links". Previously it would just open the file, even if it wasn't something I had opened. Now it always does this workspace search, which is useless for new files.

Comment: Perhaps something changed that makes it more glued to this workspace concept, which I don't really use specifically for reasons like this. If I manually add more directories to my workspace I can at least get them to surface in my "workspace search", so it's two clicks to open instead of the previous one cmd+click. Still will run into this problem if I try to open a file outside the workspace, but can `code -r file_out_of_workspace` as a backup.

Comment: @totalhack Strange. Could you detail this issue in a separate question?