# Is there a way of opening a file from the integrated terminal into a specific editor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Following [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41377489/4756173), it's possible to open a specific file from the integrated terminal via:

```bash
code -r <filename>
```

However, what if, in order to be more organized, I wished to open certain files in certain editors? This would be very useful for quickly creating certain types of boilerplate setups...

I'm guessing it could be something like this?

```bash
code -r --editor 1 <filename>
```

Comment: I don't think so, see your command line options here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible yet, but it could be, you just need to upvote [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160088#issuecomment-1242621381) I've created.