# VSCode "Open file in editor" hover not working in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

When I get a syntax error in Python I think VSCode is supposed to offer a mouse hover over the error message, which lets you Ctrl-click to go to the errored line in the editor.

I'm not getting the hover on the final line in the traceback (but it works OK on earlier lines).

I think it's some kind of configuration problem - but what?

This does work - I get "Open file in editor" (mouse at red arrow):

[image]

But this doesn't work (no hover message; mouse at red arrow):

[image]

(naturally, per Murphy's Law, the latter is the one I *want* to work, as the error is in fact on line 2171.)

Comment: may be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377489/how-to-open-a-file-from-the-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that there are spaces in your file path.

[image]

To fix it, change your folder name to make the file path recognizable. Generally, the file path should be in full English, with no spaces and no special symbols.

---

Hover over the file path to see the underscore including the line number. At this point `Ctrl` + `click` will navigate to the corresponding line number of the corresponding file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know it's supposed to work that way. Problem is, it doesn't. I hover over the error line and don't get the "Open in Editor". I'll try to post a video.

Comment: Show your interface and your settings.

Comment: Interface is here: https://ibb.co/QCxr8Gn Settings are here: https://pastebin.com/eyjr86Ka

Comment: You only show one picture? How do I know what you're doing and what you're getting? In addition, your *settings.json* can not be viewed. Awesome! By the way, the example in your picture also successfully navigates to the wrong row count on my machine.

Comment: OK, here's a video: https://youtu.be/od7A_MZ63V0 (sorry the cursor is black on black in the video, but if you look closely at the white text you can see it), and here's the settings.json: https://controlc.com/95cc478a

Comment: The reason is simple: because there are spaces in the file path. . . although this is a very frustrating problem, it does exist. At the moment, to fix this, you have to modify your folder name so that the path does not contain spaces. Generally, we recommend that the file path be named in full English, no spaces, and no special characters.