# How to open a file in VS Code frontend from the ssh session to the host with VS Code backend?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

I have a macOS laptop that runs VS Code, which connects to a remote host over ssh. This host runs VS Code backend. This remote host also has a tmux session to which I connect from my laptop using iTerm and tmux integration.

If I want to open a file from the remote host in VS Code I usually just hit ⌘+p and select it. But this works only for the files in the working directory. If I want to open a file outside the working directory, I need to hit ⌘+o and then input the whole path to the file, which is tedious.

I see a `code-server` process from `~/.vscode-server/bin` running on the host. While I'm in a tmux ssh session I would like to run something like

```
open-in-vs-code-frontend filename
```

and it would open in my VS Code window. Is there a way to do this?

This question is different from [How to open a file from the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41377489/261217), since I am not using the integrated terminal.

Comment: don't talk about `frontend` and `backend`, it is the `local` VSC and `remote` VSC